# Can I distribute the native iOS app for 1000 people WITHOUT using Apple App Store/TestFight?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have a requirement to distribute the iOS app for some limited users using a link.

Can I distribute the native iOS app for 1000 people WITHOUT using the Apple App Store/TestFight? (Also, without taking their device UDID)

I tried diawi platform, but it has some validity for the link and also it will require the device UDID added.

Also, is there any way to do it using Heroku app platform?

Comment: You can use an enterprise program membership or a custom B2B app and an MDM server if they are employees of your company, otherwise, no.

Comment: [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)